# What does a rose coloured ship on the minimap mean?

Tags: world-of-warships

One of my allied ships is in a pinkish colour on the minimap.

What in the name of Triton does that mean?

[image]

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have a picture, would you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pink ship means that this is a Player with a high Teamkilling/Teamdamag rate.

You will get penalized for shooting these Players but if he does damage to you he will recieve double the damage.

Comment: Hmm, basically be alert and possibly stay away from these losers.

Comment: @Nelson Yes but usually the die before they can kill you.

Comment: Ah yes; there was one nutter in that round who started firing on our own side for no apparent reason, guess that was them. Thanks!

Comment: Note that as of 0.5.5, it's become quite easy to get a pink icon - just one team kill will do it (and yes, that's one too many, but accidents do occasionally happen). So while it's good to be wary of pink ships, it's also worth giving them the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: I was pink myself for a while. It's very easy, especially with torpedoes.