# Is it allowed to kill teamkillers?

Tags: world-of-warships

[This](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/262988/what-does-a-rose-coloured-ship-on-the-minimap-mean) question has an explanation, that pink players cannot be killed without penalty. Pink are the players who are teamkillers or who made a damage on allied ships.

So if I kill some pink players - I will be pink myself.

Is there any situation, thas allow you to kill teamkillers wihtout penalty? Maybe such a players will be marked with other colour?

Answer (score 3):

Even if they are a teamkiller, they are still a part of your team, and you will be appropriately punished for attacking them (getting the team killer marking yourself). Do not worry about the team killer doing further team damage, once you have that marking any more team damage is reflected back at you.

Comment: In world of tanks it is allowed to kill TKs without penalty

Comment: but this question not about WoT

Comment: The login behind this is that it is much easier to accidentally kill a team-mate in WoW than WoT. In fact a bad player can get himself killed by turning on to your torpedoes, even if you aimed them nowhere near him.